# Memory leak message on initialization

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks

I'm getting a rare message, whats happening?

Deffinition:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) SoundPlayer* soundPlayer;
```

Code:

```
SoundPlayer *soundPlayerTemp = [[SoundPlayer alloc] init];
self.soundPlayer = soundPlayerTemp;
[soundPlayerTemp release];
```

Message:

```
Potential leak of an object allocated on line
```

Comment: can you post your SoundPlayer code?

Answer (score 0):

The static analyzer is full of false positives; there is nothing wrong with your code. You could be more succinct and get rid of the message with the following:

```
self.soundPlayer = [[[SoundPlayer alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Or by switching to ARC, which is also an excellent choice.

Comment: @Daniel Automatic Reference Counting, basically automatic retain/release for IOS5 (and some later versions of 4.x)

Comment: The static analyser would not flag a memory leak in the original bit of code.  There must be something else going on.

Comment: In fact the something else going on is probably that the property is not released in dealloc.

Comment: @Daniel can you post your implementation of `dealloc`?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of the issue is that you do not release the property in your dealloc method.  You should have something like:

```
-(void) dealloc
{
    self.soundPlayer = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Or, if you have explicitly declared an instance variable to back the property, the recommended code is

```
-(void) dealloc
{
    [soundPlayer release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```